# C++ core dump caused by "Hello world"

Tags: c++, ubuntu, memory, g++

I was testing Vim to write code and wrote a simple "Hello world" program to test it. Using g++, the program seemingly compiled fine with the command

```
g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld
```

(no error messages)
but when I try to execute it with

```
./helloworld
```

I get several errors about 'std::bad_alloc' and a message stating that my core has been dumped. I am using the most up to date version of Ubuntu on 64 bit architecture and g++ and Vim and wrote, compiled and tried to execute the program in the command line. My program is below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    cout << "Hello world\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Please let me know what I may be doing wrong, I have tested the program on other computers and believe it works fine.
Thanks!

Comment: This suggests a mismatch between the compiler and the installed `libstdc++`. This shouldn't happen, this indicates that your system got corrupted, and figuring out why will require a careful inspection and a hands-on examination of your Ubuntu system, so it's unlikely that anyone here can help you. You will need to figure it out yourself. It might be faster for you to reformat your hard drive and reinstall Ubuntu from scratch.

Comment: Well, definitely not reproducible, everything you did is fine. No clue what might be causing `bad_alloc` in such a simple app. Did you play with gcc or libstdc++ installation?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with Vim.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks, I will reinstall my OS. I have a SSD not a hard drive, does that change anything? Do I still need to reformat it?

Comment: @pptaszni Hi! I didn't change anything with them, I just installed them and left them at their default settings

Comment: All hard drives are reformatted using the same process. Just run the Ubuntu installer, delete all existing partitions, and let the Ubuntu installer create the default partitions automatically.